# I'm getting an exception in a server when I'm trying to compare a command line argument vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, cmd, arguments

I'm working with an application that someone gave to modify. I'm trying to compare the command line arg gave by the user in the CMD with an specific command, in my laptop it works well but when I upload to a Windows Server it get an exception message:

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection".

This is my code line:

```
If My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0) <> "ShowApp" Then
   If sService = "Ipswitch SSH Server" Or sService = "Ipswitch WS_FTP Server" Then
      IPSwitchRestartService(sService)
   End If
End If
```

When I executed the application with double click in my laptop everything works fine, but in the server is throwing the exception.

Any idea?

Comment: It would appear that no command line argument is present.  Assuming that first line is what's throwing the exception.  Some logging output can help determine that if live debugging isn't an option (since it's running on another server).

Comment: Awesome dude! I foudnd a solution and it's validateing that the commandline <> 0, you're correct man.